# Update my documents in Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor

I want to update my documents in Meteor.

> update failed: Match failed

Error is caused by:

```
Template.KullaniciListele.events({
  'click .kaydet': function (event,template) {
    event.preventDefault();
        var tel = template.$('#telno').val();
        Meteor.users.update(this._id), {
          "$set": {
          tel:tel
          }
      };
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1. Check your code, and make it look pretty - otherwise you can't even see errors yourself. First, you have error here (how does it work at all?):

```
Meteor.users.update(this._id, {
   $set: {
      tel: tel
   }
});
```

Step 2. Try checking the value of `this._id`